# Retrieving members present in a voice channel

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm getting really close on something I'm working on with a node.js Discord bot but really stuck at this point. I'm trying to retrieve the name and id of all members in a the same voice channel as the person running the command. However, I'm having a tough time mapping out the last step to extract those from the data. Here's what I have:

```
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.author.bot) {
    return;
  }
  if (message.content === '!tausbot sunday') {
      const channeltoCheck = message.member.voice.id;
      console.log('channeltoCheck:');
      console.log(channeltoCheck);

      const membersofChannel = message.guild.members.cache.find(channeltoCheck => channeltoCheck.id == channeltoCheck);
      console.log(membersofChannel);
  
      const myArray = {};

      membersofChannel.each(member => {
          myArray.push(`${member.user.tag} (ID: ${member.user.id})`)
      });

  message.channel.send(`**MEMBERS**\n${myArray.join("\n") || "No members found"}`);
  } 
});
```

membersofChannel gets me the data that goes fine to console.log, but I need to pull the username and id out of that and post it in the message. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I think I may have a bigger problem too - it seems I'm only pulling one member, though I have myself and two dummy accounts in the voice channel. Here's the bit that includes the member:
[image: console view]

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're using `.find` to find the members. This will not work. Below is what you should use to replace it. `.filter` will return a Collection that can be used with the snippet after.

```js
.filter(member => member.voice.channelID === channelToCheck);
// Filter by their voice channel
```

Assuming that you're returned either an Array or an individual GuildMember, you can put all the data in a new Array. Then, you would join all the data using `Array.join()`. This puts it into a nice clean list.

```js
const myArray = {}; // Create an Array to put the new data in
membersofChannel.each(member => { // For each member, do...
  myArray.push(`${member.user.tag} (ID: ${member.user.id})`) // Pull the username and ID
});
message.channel.send(`**MEMBERS**\n${myArray.join("\n") || "No members found"}`)
// Separate entries with a new line
// Send the message containing the information
```

The `.join("\n")` will separate each member with a new line. Say Joe#0001 and Bob#0001 are in a VC and they run the command. It'll return the following:

> **MEMBERS**
> Joe#0001 (ID: 1234567890)
> Bob#0001 (ID: 1234567890)

Comment: Thanks so much - and thanks for commenting in reasoning. I'm so new at this and all of that information is helpful. When I place that code, I get error:

TypeError: membersofChannel.each is not a function

I'll update my code above and also a piece of what I'm getting in console for membersofChannel.

Comment: My answer has been edited. Please take a look and if it answers your question, tick the check mark to show others that this helped you out!